# Angular Translate doesn't work with multiple translation IDs

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

This doesn't work. Returns a blank.

```
 $translate('INVEST_EDU', 'MOST_ULTIMATE').then(function (investEdu, mostUltimate) {
```

Then I tried this, with an object:

```
 $translate('INVEST_EDU', 'MOST_ULTIMATE').then(function (translations) {
```

Accessing it like `translations.INVEST_EDU'. First one appears, second one blank.

What am I doing wrong here, in making [Angular-translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) work with multiple translation IDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular translate usage:

> $translate(translationId[, interpolateParams], interpolationId);
>
> translationId [string | array] - A token which represents a
>   translation id This can be optionally an array of translation ids
>   which results that the function returns an object where each key is
>   the translation id and the value the translation.
>
> interpolateParams(optional) [object]-An object hash for dynamic values
>
> interpolationId   [string] - The id of the interpolation to use

http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate

This means, if you want multiple translation ids you call soemthing like `$translate(['INVEST_EDU','MOST_ULTIMATE']).then(function(results){...}`

Comment: Yes, I was missing the `[ ]`